# Position of a pattern in a character list in R

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

What i want to do is search for a specific pattern in a list of characters and return the positions so I can exclude them later on.

My data is a text where each word has a Part-of-Speech-Tag attached, in the format of:

```
test
$text
[1] "This/DT is/VBZ a/DT short/JJ sentence/NN ,/, to/TO test/VB if/IN everything/NN is/VBZ working/VBG ./."
$POStags
 [1] "DT"  "VBZ" "DT"  "JJ"  "NN"  "$,"   "TO"  "VB"  "IN"  "NN"  "VBZ"
[12] "VBG" "$."
```

I want to filter for all occurences of "$." and "$,". I've tried the following:

```
grep("$.", test$POStags, value = TRUE)
```

which returns `character(0)`

I'm new to R and have the feeling there should be an easy solution for this, but somehow I just can't get it to work... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try with `\$\.` and `\$,`. `$` means "asserts position at the end of the string", you need "\" to match char `$`.

Comment: $ sign has a special meaning in regular expressions. It means "end of the line". You must escape it using "\\$" instead of "$".

Comment: . sign has also a special meaning. It means "any character". You also need to escape it.

Comment: Just use `grep("$", test$POStags, value=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep("\\$(\\.|,)", test$POStags)
[1]  6 13
```

Comment: Your answer is not useful if we have values like "$$","$%" etc. It will give you result for all values starting with $. Please check my solution.

Comment: You missed the part about matching only `$.` or `$,`. You need something like `grep("\\$[\\.,]", test$POStags)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
which(grepl("$.",test$POStags,fixed = T) | grepl("$,",test$POStags,fixed = T))
```

Comment: Is that the reason why you downvotes the answer? Reread the question. He wanted to filter all occurrences of $. That’s what he wanted so g@ve him the answer with respect to the question. Also when an answer has the same idea, yet you feel it is lacking something, you need not downvote it. You only downvote when the answer is completely wrong and doesn’t solve the task at hand. There is an edit button. You can edit the answer

Comment: Sir, Please reread this line "I want to filter for all occurences of "$." and "$,". I've tried the following"

Comment: Yes. Then look at the example given and tell me whether the solution I provided did not solve the issue at hand

Comment: Your solution is right but not safe to use. Thats what I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is your code filters $67,which is still sillimar to mine which filters 6$7

Comment: According to this specific question and example given, the code I gave did solve the task at hand and that’s why it was accepted. Please if you don’t mind, may you reverse the downvote

Comment: Also the problem was to find a match of $in a string. Whether it is in the first position or last it was not specified. We are on substituting the $ part. We are just detecting whether it is in the string. That is the work of grep. We need not to use the lazy notation here. We are just interested in $

Comment: Sure! I will do that.

Comment: @Rushabh If you disagree with the OP, it's better to post a comment, and allow Onyambu to review it himself. Or, post the different version in your own answer.

Comment: @jpaugh I feel above answer is still inappropriate that is why I changed my answer.